# Magento2: How to create multiple storefronts

Tags: magento2, multistore, websites

I'm trying to create new store & website which will run at `http://127.0.0.1/lapis/in/`. Here is the process I've followed.
1. Created new store, website and store view named `Indian Store`, `Indian website` & `Indian Store view` respectively with website code **in**.
2. In `Stores->Configuration->Web` changed website URL to `http://127.0.0.1/lapis/in/`. 
3. Assigned category at products->Categories after switching store view to Indian Store view.

4. Created folder named **in** inside root magento installation with 2 files index.php and .htaccess with following code
   `index.php` code inside `in` directory

> ```
> $params = $_SERVER;
> $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'in';
> $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
> $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
> $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('..\Magento\Framework\App\Http');
> $bootstrap->run($app);
> ```

5. Copied .htaccess root file inside `in` directory and added 
    RewriteBase /in/
   Now when I'm navigating to `http://127.0.0.1/lapis/` , it works fine but `http://127.0.0.1/lapis/in/` throws 500 server error.
   I'm missing something here or my process of creating new website is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In 
   `$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('..\Magento\Framework\App\Http'); $bootstrap->run($app);` you should not use '..', as it's class name
2. I'd also suggest to check your web server logs to better understand the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix it with help of server logs. Page is loading static contents are not deployed to `in/pub` directory. Developer mode is on and also I've deployed content manually using `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` . It is trying to use js/css resources from path `http://127.0.0.1/lapis/in/pub/` but nothing is deployed in `in/pub/` directory. Is there a different method to deploy static content for different websites?

Comment: They should not be deployed in `in/pub`, all static assets should remain in `pub`. What you can do to fix it is to specify custom Base URL for  Static View Files in Stores > Configuration > Web. It should point to regular `pub`, not to `in/pub`, which becomes default path when you specify custom Base URL for the website.

Comment: i have set multiple website but in new website css not render properly. I have set luma theme for new website but css not render. which issue may be possible for this?

Comment: @rakesh, have you specified specify custom Base URL for Static View Files?

Comment: which url we have to defined at that location, plz suggest me.

Comment: For the topic's example with a website http://127.0.0.1/lapis/in/ , URL for static view files should be http://127.0.0.1/lapis/pub/static/ If it's not specified Magento just adds 'pub/static' to the base URL and you get ' http://127.0.0.1/lapis/in/pub/static', which is incorrect.

Comment: @BuskaMuza I've a nginx & configure the virutalhost for my local Magento2.4.3 setup, I followed the above way, but it's showing as 404.

Answer (score 4):

Here I am sharing working code for create multiple website in magento2 (2.0.4)

Create new sub website folder in Magento root folder.

Copy your Magento root index.php and .htaccess files and paste it new created website folder.

Open index.php file from new website folder and replace code

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
    $bootstrap->run($app);
```

With

```
$params = $_SERVER;
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website_code'; 
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('\Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Now create new sub website with it's store and store view.
    -

- Create a new sub website.
- Create a new store with select sub website and sub website category.
- Create a new store view with select sub website store.

Set theme for new created sub website.

Stores >> Configuration >> Select Sub Website from store view drop
   down >> Design >> Design Theme  >> select theme for Sub Website and
   save.    (We can set Magento Blank theme for testing purpose)

set new sub website URLs like this

Please got to Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> Select your Sub
   Website from store view drop down >> Web >> Base URLs

**Base URL  :** `http://1270.0.1/magento-2.0.4/sub_website/`

**Base Link URL :** `http://1270.0.1/magento-2.0.4/sub_website/`

**Base URL for Static View Files** : `http://1270.0.1/magento-2.0.4/pub/static/`

**Base URL for User Media Files :** `http://1270.0.1/magento-2.0.4/pub/media/`

And do the same for Base URLs (Secure)

Now Run command for deploy static content : 
   Now run command for clean cache :

Done !!!

Now run and check base and new created website on browser.

Like :

**Base website URL :**  `http://1270.0.1/magento-2.0.4/`

You will see this website selected category and theme

**Sub website URL :**    `http://1270.0.1/magento-2.0.4/sub_website/`

You will see this website category and theme

If display all content properly then it is Done !!!