# Magento2.1: How to create multiple websites with different domains

Tags: magento2, multistore, multidomain, cloud

I deployed Magento 2.1 on console.google
Is there anybody who succeded to deploy multiple websites with different domains?
[Magento2: How to create multiple storefronts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98299/magento2-how-to-create-multiple-storefronts#new-answer) 
does not works for Magento 2.1

I am sure many people suffer the same issue?

There is not any answer to similar question for Magento 2.1 on link 
[How to setup another domain/website on the same Magento 2.1.0 installation? (updated)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131487/how-to-setup-another-domain-website-on-the-same-magento-2-1-0-installation-upd)

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple websites or store views in Magento 2 admin panel and map unique domains to each of them.

**Step 1:** Point all domains to `pub` in Magento's root directory

**Step 2:** Configure domain names as base URLs for each website in System Configuration in Magento admin panel.

**Step 3:** Set store or website for each domain as environment variable in `.htaccess` of `pub` directory or in the webserver configuration.

- Example with the websites as given in the question:

  ```
  SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
  SetEnvIf Host abc\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
  SetEnvIf Host xyz\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
  ```
- Example with store views instead of websites

  ```
  SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
  SetEnvIf Host abc\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store_code_1
  SetEnvIf Host xyz\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store_code_2
  ```

  These configurations check if the domain **contains** "abc.com" or "xyz.com", which I find useful to also match subdomains or test systems like abc.com.testserver.com or test.abc.com, using the same .htaccess file. If you want exact matching, replace `abc\.com` with `^abc\.com$`

**Step 4:** Clear cache and access your domains.

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

In the config for your stores, just enter the URLs as they are, not the install URL. Then, on the alternative domain (otherstore.com), use the default htaccess (when it is in root, otherwise add rewrite in htaccess)and put just this inside the index.php:

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'websitecode';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

The following is key though, i did not get it to work otherwise, au contraire Magento 1 where we had lots of stores without this. Go to your other store root with ssh and enter this:

```
ln -s /path/to/your/install/public_html/m2/app/ app 
ln -s /path/to/your/install/public_html/m2/lib/ lib 
ln -s /path/to/your/install/public_html/m2/pub/ pub 
ln -s /path/to/your/install/public_html/m2/var/ var
```

After we added the latter, everything seems to work fine, so far.

Good luck!